# ggplot : multiple lines starting from the same point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like this one :

```
df <- data.frame(Species = c("Sp A", "Other sp", "Other sp", "Other sp",
                       "Sp A", "Other sp", "Other sp"), 
           Study = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
                     "B", "B", "B"), 
           Value = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7))
```

Looks like this :

```
> df
   Species Study Value
1     Sp A     A     1
2 Other sp     A     3
3 Other sp     A     4
4 Other sp     A     5
5     Sp A     B     3
6 Other sp     B     6
7 Other sp     B     7
```

I would like to compare the values of the species A to the values of the other species from a same study.
This is the plot I have now :

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Value, x = Species)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(group = Study), color = "gray50") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

I don't want the vertical lines. Instead of this, I would like to have 5 lines, 3 starting from the lower "Sp A" point toward the 3 corresponding "Other sp" points from the same study (A) and 2 starting from the upper "Sp A" toward the 2 other points from the same study (B).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but here's a solution that works.  The trick is to rearrange the data slightly and then use `geom_segment`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Species = c("Sp A", "Other sp", "Other sp", "Other sp",
                             "Sp A", "Other sp", "Other sp"), 
                 Study = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
                           "B", "B", "B"), 
                 Value = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7))

# Split data
other <- df %>% filter(Species == "Other sp")
sp_a <- df %>% filter(Species == "Sp A")

# Recombine into the data set for plotting
df <- other %>%
  inner_join(sp_a, by = "Study")

# Make the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = Species.y, y = Value.y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Species.x, yend = Value.x, colour = Study))
```

[image: Multiple line segments as desired. Further tweaks for labels, points, etc. still needed]

Adjust the plot as desired!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will wait to see if there is no more direct way before accepting your answer. By the way I think that you should remove the `slice` line. This is unnecessary and is causes the multiplication of identical lines.  Same result in base R with `merge(df[df$Species == "Sp A",], df[df$Species != "Sp A",], by = "Study", all = TRUE)`

Comment: That would be a case of trying one thing and then changing directions mid-answer!  I've now corrected the answer.

Comment: This is the only way to do it, unless there are unique identifiers for "Other sp". There's no way in your data to distinguish between the "Other sp"-"Sp A" pair at `value=6` and `value=7` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `geom_line` if, for each level of `Study`, you duplicate the number of `Sp A` rows to match the number of `Other sp` rows and then assign a unique ID to each pair of `Sp A` and `Other Sp` for the `group` aesthetic.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Study) %>% 
  slice(c(rep(1,length(Species[Species=="Other sp"])),2:n())) %>%  
  group_by(Study, Species) %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0(Study, 1:n())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Value, x=Species, group=ID, colour=Study)) + 
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]